# Проблема импорта БД MySQL

Tags: denwer, mysql

Прислали файл - test.mdf. Размер 100 Мб. При импорте оказалось, что есть лимит в Денвере - 2 Мб примерно, что посоветуете делать?

Comment: mssql или mysql? что и куда вы импортируете?

Вы случайно не в phpmyadmin mdf грузите?

Comment: да, в пхпмайадмин гружу ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mdf - это формат хранения баз данных [Microsoft SQL Server](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server). Никаким образом вы не сможете его втянуть напрямую в mysql. Чтобы с ним работать, установите себе [экспресс-версию mssql](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/ru/ru/editions/express.aspx), в комплекте с ней идёт [SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms365247.aspx).

На дружественном сайте было про это:

- [How to import a SQL Server .bak file into MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156279/how-to-import-a-sql-server-bak-file-into-mysql)
- [Import data from Microsoft SQL (.MDF) file into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377252/import-data-from-microsoft-sql-mdf-file-into-mysql)
- [How do I convert files .mdf & .ldf to mysql format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315582/how-do-i-convert-files-mdf-ldf-to-mysql-format)
- [Importing data to MySQL from MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182784/importing-data-to-mysql-from-ms-sql)

Answer (score 0):

причем тут mdf к mysql?
для изменения лимита загрузки отредактируйте файл ini.php

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

Comment: в денвере пробовал менять, изменения принимает но в админке пишет 8 Мб. может я не правильно исправляю?

Comment: перезагрузить денвер надо.

Answer (score 0):

***.mdf — это формат образа Alchohol 120%, если мне не изменяет память, но никак не дамп БД. Так зачем его загружать в БД? Если вам необходимо организовать файловый сервер, не храните* неинформационные* данные в базе данных, сохраняйте только информацию о них (путь, размер, дату создания), а сами файлы загружайте напрямую в директорию.
А про изменение лимита загрузки файла можно почитать здесь - http://bloginru.ru/2010/05/04/import-bolshix-baz-dannyx-v-denver/

Comment: В данном случае скорее всего *.mdf это формат файла баз данных Microsoft Sql Server, а не образ диска.